# How to upgrade a project in Unity Hub

Tags: unity

Before Unity Hub, it used to be the case that if you opened up a project that was from an older version, you would be prompted to upgrade the project.

I am now on the latest Unity Hub 2.0.0 and I am trying to open a project that was last saved with `2018.2.1f1` but I am unable to.
From installs, I am able to download and install the closest available version, `2018.2.21f1`, but anytime I try to open my project I get the message

> Missing editor version 2018.2.1f1 on this machine. Select another version from the list or install the missing one.

How can I upgrade this project like we did in older versions?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The entry in the Unity Version column is a drop-down menu. Click on it and you can select one of your installed versions to which to upgrade your project. Remember to save a backup elsewhere first!

[image]

In older versions of the Unity Hub, this drop-down menu would only work if you had at least two versions of Unity installed (whether or not either of them matched the project version). But as of the last time I checked in 2020, this now works even if you have only a single version installed.

Comment: Wow I thought I had clicked on every dropdown in every window. Looks like that one escaped me.

Comment: Important point to add: This doesn't work when you only have the new version installed. You specifically must have both the old and the new version installed for the dropdown appear and allowing you to switch versions… horrible design IMO.

Comment: That does not match my experience, Mario. I've definitely upgraded from versions I no longer had installed. But it might be the case that you need one other version, whether it matches the project's old version or not.

Answer (score 5):

I can verify PixelCake's issue, and elaborate on Mario's reply. You don't specifically need **the** older version to be installed - literally any other version present on the system will allow you to upgrade.

With only one Unity version installed, you will get no dropdown under the Unity Version column, and the version number appears as simple text. Clicking the text does nothing. Clicking the project name fails to open the project, and displays the error as PixelCake reported.

To reproduce this effect, install Unity 2019.2.6f1 from the [download page](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive), and create and save an empty project with that version. Uninstall **all** Unity versions, then install any higher version (as of this writing, 2019.2.8f1 is the highest). Make sure this is the only version installed. Then, try to open your project. The "Unity Version" column will be text, not a dropdown, showing the only installed Unity version. Opening the project through Unity Hub will be impossible, giving the error reported in the original post:

[image: Unity Hub with one version installed]

However! Now install *any other Unity version*. In this example (just to illustrate the point) I installed a very old Unity version, 2017.1.5f1. With two+ versions available, the dropdown is now present, and the project can be opened in 2019.2.8f1:

[image: Unity Hub with two versions installed]

Note that the little orange caution sign is gone. You can now select the higher version, upgrade the project, then delete the dummy install that forced the dropdown to appear.

Assertion: **I should be able to upgrade my project to a newer version of Unity, even if that's the only version installed.**

Comment: I went to the [Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/upgrading-a-project-should-not-require-two-unity-installations.755411) to post this there, and it looks like an intermittent/regression issue with Unity Hub.

They appear to be aware of it, and hopefully with Hub 2.1.3+, it won't be an issue.

Comment: Found a workaround, re-add the project folder to Unity Hub, and it will allow the upgrade, even with only one version of Unity installed.

Comment: This was so useful... thank you!